# Select first day of month in presto

Tags: presto

I'm trying to select the first day of the month for a date value in Presto (Hive Table).  I've tried `TRUNC(date,'MM')` which works in Hive but not Presto.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`date_trunc('month', date_value)`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#truncation-function)

```
presto> select date_trunc('month', DATE '2018-05-24');
   _col0
------------
 2018-05-01
(1 row)
```